# VUE JS component is appending with existing blade contents

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am running into one small bug Laravel with vue js, I am converting already devleoped app module one by one to VUE JS, everthing worked fine routing etc, only issue is if I am on current view i.e home which is extended by my main layout file i.e
[image: main blade file]

so whenever I click on new module which have been developed by vuejs its got simply appended to the previous view how can I avoid this?
as I also don't want to disturb all previous setup as full app is not currently developed in vue so we must need content for rest of the application to work as it was working previously!

Comment: you need to create `MainLayout` component which will be extend new module so you can make new layout in vuejs

Comment: @KamleshPaul thanks would you like to share some example?

Comment: in blade only `<div id="app"></div>` then in `main.vue` will have router link with new layout

Comment: I do have already, my app is not fully done with vue yet, that's why I am trying to do module by module!, what to work with both router-view and also href for laravel routing by default!